# How to get test cases list in Robot Framework without launching the actual tests?

Tags: python, robotframework

I have file test.robot with test cases.

How can i get the list of this test cases without activating the tests, from command line or python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check out [testdoc tool](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-data-documentation-tool-testdoc). Like explained in the doc, "The created documentation is in HTML format and it includes name, documentation and other metadata of each test suite and test case".

Answer (score 15):

Robot test suites are easy to parse with the robot parser:

```
from robot.parsing.model import TestData
suite = TestData(parent=None, source=path_to_test_suite)
for testcase in suite.testcase_table:
    print(testcase.name)
```

Comment: I got error when importing TestData from your above module

Comment: @LinhNhatNguyen see my answer.

Answer (score 6):

**For v3.2 and up:**

In RobotFramework 3.2 [the parsing APIs have been rewritten](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/rf-3.2.rst#parsing-apis-have-been-rewritten), so the answer from Bryan Oakley won't work on these versions anymore.

The proper code that is compatible with both pre-3.2 and post-3.2 versions is the following:

```
from robot.running import TestSuiteBuilder
from robot.model import SuiteVisitor


class TestCasesFinder(SuiteVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tests = []

    def visit_test(self, test):
        self.tests.append(test)


builder = TestSuiteBuilder()
testsuite = builder.build('testsuite/')
finder = TestCasesFinder()
testsuite.visit(finder)

print(*finder.tests)
```

Further reading:

- [Visitor model](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodoc/robot.model.html#module-robot.model.visitor)
- [`TestSuiteBuilder` class reference](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodoc/robot.running.builder.html#robot.running.builder.builders.TestSuiteBuilder)

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer! I just wondering why we need the asterisk here print(*finder.tests)

Comment: @LinhNhatNguyen I don't remember to be honest, probably just to get rid of `[` and `]` from the output.